# Click on the other side of a vertical split in Emacs

Tags: emacs, mouse, putty

I split emacs vertically and have `xterm-mouse-mode` enabled (I am using PuTTY). If I split the left half horizontally, I can use my mouse to easily click between the buffers. If I attempt to click the right side, it becomes overtaken by a minibuffer window and I must close it and `C-x o` over like normal.

How can I configure Emacs to just let me click the right side?

Comment: Indeed, as I've mentioned in my post!

Comment: And that should teach me to read more carefully, sorry :). I deleted my comment.

Comment: No worries, we've all been there!

Comment: What major mode, please, is the buffer that you click which results in a minibuffer being opened?

Comment: How can I check that, exactly?

Comment: Essentially, I am looking for a way to duplicate what you are seeing so that I can troubleshoot the issue, or at least have a better understanding.  While inside the buffer that results in the unexpected behavior of the minibuffer opening, you can use:  `C-h m` and that will tell you what major mode, and a list of all the minor modes.  The major mode will help us understand a little better what is happening.  A screenshot would also help (perhaps a lot).